# Мобильная версия сайта Bitrix, автоматическое перенаправление на мобильный шаблон

Tags: битрикс, мобильная-разработка

Доброе утро!
Решил сделать мобильную версию отдельным шаблон, встал вопрос перенаправления и в последующем корректная работа всего этого дела. Прошерстив сеть нашел следующую реализацию, в файле init.php добавил код:

```
<?
if (isset ($_GET['type'])){
switch ($_GET['type']) {
case 'pda':
setcookie('siteType', 'pda', time()+3600*24*30,'/');
define('siteType','pda');
break;
default:
setcookie('siteType', 'original', time()+3600*24*30,'/');
define('siteType','original');
}
}
else{
$checkType='';
if (isset($_COOKIE['siteType'])) $checkType=$_COOKIE['siteType'];
switch ($checkType) {
case 'pda':
define('siteType','pda');
break;
default:
define('siteType','');
}
}
?>
```

А непосредственно в шаблоне с которого будет редирект в header.php:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/custom-files/Mobile-Detect-2.8.34/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if (($detect->isMobile()) && ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "gippokrat.ru" || $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "www.gippokrat.ru") && empty($VISITOR_ID)) {
    $APPLICATION->set_cookie("MOBILE_VISITOR_MB", "MOBILE", time()+30*24*60*60);
    LocalRedirect("https://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "?type=pda");
exit();
}
?>
```

Если кто-нибудь таким же или похожим способ реализовал мобильную версию, то наведите на путь истинный.

Вопросы и трудности:
1. Зачем для мобильного шаблона отправляем 2 cookie в header("MOBILE_VISITOR_MB", "MOBILE") и в init('siteType', 'pda')?
2. И для чего в init определяем константу define она ведь bool возвращает, что она тут дает?

Comment: А что мешает отдельный шаблон подгружать для сайта по условию и по регулярке или другому варианту включайте этот шаблон. Это делается в настройках сайта. Документация в этом вам поможет.

Comment: Ничего не мешает, тем более здесь я так понимаю шаблон и подключается по условию.
Понимаете, я сейчас только пытаюсь разобраться во все этом и задал конкретные вопросы, но вместо ответа на них услышал другой вопрос который меня больше запутал.
И если вы говорите про документацию, то хотя бы ссылайте на что-то конкретное, у bitrix документации мне хватит читать на пару месяцев.